# SonicWALL TZ 190 Speed Issues

Tags: security, performance, sonicwall, settings

I recently installed a TZ 190 firewall and it is extremely slow when the security services are activated on the LAN zone. The firmware is SonicOS Enhanced 3.9.0.1-6e. It seems to load webpages extremely slow and the ping is around 40 ms. Other than updating the firmware and disabling the security services, has anyone had any luck speeding the TZ 190s up? I'm going to update the firmware tonight.

Comment: Well, I turned off the antivirus and antispyware security features and it seems to work fine now, but I think that's the whole purpose I bought the firewall :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was your CPU load in the firewall when you had these services turned on?  I've run both tz 150 and currently tz 180 without any issues and used both services.

Comment: The CPU load is not even getting close to 20-30% at peak times. The firewall's web interface is about the only thing that is making the CPU that high. I think it has something to do with the throughput of the antivirus gateway and the antispyware gateway. Once I turned both these services off, everything is good to go. I went to SonicWall's forum, and the only answer they had was to upgrade to a better firewall.

Comment: Well, Sonicwall didn't say that, but other users on their forums did.

Answer (score 1):

From our experience this is normal behavior for the small TZ and even the old PRO version of Sonicwalls.  Any of the deep packet inspectors (AV, AS and IPS) severely impact throughput of the firewall.  Currently we are running the NSA2400s and they are able to keep up with our 100+ users...  
But for the money, these still offer the best features, in our opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed the older TZ170. Updating the firmware regardless of performance is always a good thing to do. In your specific case, I would try to start the firewall with the least amount of services and slowly start them one by one and monitor the CPU load after each service is enabled.

A lot of the features are CPU intensive so it would probably be best to narrow down which feature is causing the load to increase substantially and then tune it accordingly. There may also be default settings that you're unaware of that is marginally chipping away at the CPU load so that the services you need don't have the CPU available. While I haven't managed the 190, there were numerous settings on the TZ170 that I had to dig around for so it's easy to misconfigure.